# pandas read csv returns dataframe as object type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While reading csv file `df = pd.read_csv('lightcurve.csv',header=None)` and creating the dataframe, my datatypes is in objects. How can I read my csv so that I can do `df.dropna` to remove all NULL values. There is also NULL values in my csv. Any suggestions would be great help.

The image of my data in csv file is :
[image: dataframe]

Comment: You can do `df.replace('NULL', np.nan).dropna()` to remove nans

Comment: After removing nans you can use `convert_dtypes` function to make correct column type inference

Comment: Thank you for answering but it didn't remove  'NULL' values neither it replace.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you copied some of the text of the csv file instead of [an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). As well, could you show your code and its output when you tested Naman's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided I feel this is how your data looks like.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

inp = StringIO("""1,22.3,53,5.5
23,34.5,5,7.2
43,n,n,n""")

df = pd.read_csv(inp,header=None)

print(df)

df = df.replace('n',np.nan).dropna()

print(df)
```

Comment: In stringIO module can we give a csv file because I have csv file.

Comment: Yes the example i provided is indeed a slice of some csv

Comment: I am not talking about a slice of csv whole 'lightcurve.csv' file i mean. I tried doing `data = StringIO("""lightcurve.csv""")` but it ended of creating df lightcurve.csv value.

Comment: I request you please see the image I have attached and read the question.